# Accessing data in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How so you access data in a JSON where the keys have spaces in them?
e.g.

```
{
    "New AG":"ASW",
    "Months":"apr",
    "Duration Period":"8 - 12 WEEKS",
    "New Joiners":"NA",
    "Resource Name":"xyz",
    "Personnel No":00000,
    "Resource Join Date":"xxx",
}
```

I have referred other answers on stackoverflow but none of them can be applied here or not working for this.
I have to run a loop where I have to access these keys.

Comment: It's bad practice to return named properties with spaces, can the server not remove these before returning? It would make things much simpler for you.

Comment: "but none of them can be applied here" – well, the **[very first Google hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)** can be applied perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

json["Key with spaces"] is another way to get a JSON key and it should work with spaces